# Reusing part of Stream mapping and filtering to compose two different results

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I'd like to know if there is a good way of reusing a common stream operation that varies in the end for different outputs.
The example bellow is exactly what I'm trying to compact into a one-step operation:

```
public static DepartmentInfo extractDepartmentInfo(BaselinePolicy resource) throws ResourceProcessorError {
    Function<Exception, Exception> rpe = e -> new ResourceProcessorError(e.getMessage());
    List<String> parents = 
        Objects.requireNonNull(
            Exceptions.trying(
                () -> Arrays.asList(Exceptions.dangerous(resource::getParentIds).expecting(CMException.class).throwing(rpe))
                            .stream()
                            .map(cId -> Exceptions.dangerous(cId, resource.getCMServer()::getPolicy).expecting(CMException.class).throwing(rpe))
                            .filter(policy -> PagePolicy.class.isAssignableFrom(policy.getClass()))
                            .map(PagePolicy.class::cast)
                            .filter(page -> Exceptions.dangerous(page,
                                                                 p -> Boolean.valueOf(p.getComponentNotNull(ComponentConstants.POLOPOLY_CLIENT, 
                                                                                                            ComponentConstants.IS_HOME_DEPARTMENT,
                                                                                                            Boolean.FALSE.toString())).booleanValue())
                                                      .expecting(CMException.class).throwing(rpe))
                            .map(page -> Exceptions.dangerous(page, p -> p.getExternalId().getExternalId()).expecting(CMException.class).throwing(rpe)), ResourceProcessorError.class)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    String externalId = parents.get(parents.size()-1).toString();
    List<String> list = 
        Objects.requireNonNull(
            Exceptions.trying(
                () -> Arrays.asList(Exceptions.dangerous(resource::getParentIds).expecting(CMException.class).throwing(rpe))
                            .stream()
                            .map(cId -> Exceptions.dangerous(cId, resource.getCMServer()::getPolicy).expecting(CMException.class).throwing(rpe))
                            .filter(policy -> PagePolicy.class.isAssignableFrom(policy.getClass()))
                            .map(PagePolicy.class::cast)
                            .map(page -> 
                                Exceptions.dangerous(page, 
                                        p -> p.getChildPolicy(PATH_SEGMENT) != null && 
                                             StringUtils.hasLength(SingleValued.class.cast(p.getChildPolicy(PATH_SEGMENT)).getValue())? 
                                             SingleValued.class.cast(p.getChildPolicy(PATH_SEGMENT)).getValue(): p.getName()).expecting(CMException.class).throwing(rpe))
                            .filter(val -> val != null && !val.isEmpty()), ResourceProcessorError.class)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    if(list.size() > 3) {
        list = list.subList(list.size() - 3, list.size()-1);
    }
    switch(list.size()) {
        case 0: {
            throw new ResourceProcessorError("br.com.oesp.XMLRender.error.noProduct");
        }
        case 1: {
            return DepartmentInfo.withProduct(list.get(0), externalId);
        }
        case 2: {
            return DepartmentInfo.withProduct(list.get(0), externalId).withDepartment(list.get(1));
        }
        default: {
            return DepartmentInfo.withProduct(list.get(0), externalId).withDepartment(list.get(1)).withSubDepartment(list.get(2));
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that the first step is repeated for both:

```
List<String> parents = 
    Objects.requireNonNull(
        Exceptions.trying(
            () -> Arrays.asList(Exceptions.dangerous(resource::getParentIds).expecting(CMException.class).throwing(rpe))
                        .stream()
                        .map(cId -> Exceptions.dangerous(cId, resource.getCMServer()::getPolicy).expecting(CMException.class).throwing(rpe))
                        .filter(policy -> PagePolicy.class.isAssignableFrom(policy.getClass()))
                        .map(PagePolicy.class::cast)
```

It's not only a problem for reading but specially because I'm redoing a heavy operation twice, meanwhile in a more imperative way I'd do it once.

Comment: Notice you may replace the part `policy -> PagePolicy.class.isAssignableFrom(...)` with `PagePolicy.class::isInstance`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you're trying to do:

- avoid the redundant work of creating the input array
- avoid the redundant code of the map/filter/map

The first is easy:

```
    List<Id> list = Arrays.asList(Exceptions.dangerous(resource::getParentIds)
                    .expecting(CMException.class)
                    .throwing(rpe));
```

Now you can pull streams from this source twice without rematerializing it.

The next bit is simply a Function from List to Stream:

```
Function<List<Id>, Stream<Something>> asStream = 
    list -> list.stream().map(...).filter(...).map(...);
```

Now, just start your stream with this:

```
asStream.apply(list).moreStuff().moreStuff()
```